# Nested Fragment Communication

Tags: java, android, android-fragments, interface

I want to communicate between parent and child `fragment`. I have read so many posts on SO but none of the posts seem to be useful for me.

I have 3 `Fragments` `FragmentA`, `FragmentB` and `FragmentC`.

`FragmentA` is a parent `fragment` for `FragmentB` and `FragmentB` is parent `Fragment` of `FragmentC`.

`FragmentA` has `EditText` with `TextWatcher` and a `viewpager` with tabs implemented. `FragmentB` has another `Viewpager` with Tabs.(So basically I am using Nested tab which is not recommended but I really need to use this scenario).
`FragmentC` has `recyclerView` which then shows a list of products based on selected Tabs. this works fine for me.

Now, I want to add search functionality for products in `FragmentC` (Search is performed in `webservice` and webservice for product listing is called from `FragmentC`).

To implement this What I have done so far is,
FragmentA will setup viewpager based on web response and here is a method to setup viewpager in FragmentA.(The Code refers to how I get the instance of Fragment)

```
 private void setupViewPager(ViewPager viewPager, RetailCategoryListArr retailCategoryListArr) {
        ViewPagerAdapter adapter = new ViewPagerAdapter(getChildFragmentManager());
        for (int i = 0; i < retailCategoryListArr.getData().size(); i++) {
            RetailerCategoryArr retailerCategoryArr = retailCategoryListArr.getData().get(i);
            FragmentB FragB= FragmentB.newInstance(retailerCategoryArr, retailerArr.getUrlIdentifier());
            adapter.addFragment(FragB, retailerCategoryArr.getName());
        }
        viewPager.setAdapter(adapter);
        tabs.setupWithViewPager(viewPager);
    }
```

`FragmentB` has another `ViewPager` which then implemented like this.

```
private void setUpViewPager(ViewPager viewpager) {
        ViewPagerAdapter adapter = new ViewPagerAdapter(getChildFragmentManager());

        for (int i = 0; i < retailerCategoryArr.getChild().size(); i++) {
            RetailerCategoryArr.RetailerSubCategoryArr retailerSubCategoryArr = retailerCategoryArr.getChild().get(i);
            FragmentC FragC = FragmentC.newInstance(retailerSubCategoryArr.getId(), retailer);
            adapter.addFragment(FragC, retailerSubCategoryArr.getName());

        }
        viewpager.setAdapter(adapter);
        tabs.setupWithViewPager(viewpager);
    }
```

So, the question is how can I listen the `textchange` of `Edittext` of `FragmentA` in `FragmentC`?
If this can be possible by Interface then How?

Comment: https://developer.android.com/training/basics/fragments/communicating.html

Comment: @Kuffs Thanks for your reply. But i already read this post and i really don't get this how this can be achieved in my scenario. can you please write your answer in some brief.

Comment: If you are having trouble following the documented way of Fragment communication then you should probably edit your question to explain exactly what issue you are experiencing and why you are having trouble. Nobody wants to duplicate the documentation for you.

Answer (score 1):

From `FragmentC` try to do this:

```
Fragment frag = getParentFragment(); //it will be FragmentB
FragmentA fragA = (FragmentA)frag.getParentFragment();
fragA.editText.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher() {
    ...
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You can make interface and implements in Parent Activity to listen textwatcher from fragment A.

```
 interface Test{
      void setTextChange(String ch);
    }
```

In Parent Activity you implement listener

```
public class FragmenA extends Fragment{
    Test mCallback;
    public Edittext;


    @Override
    public void onAttach(Activity activity) {
        super.onAttach(activity);

        // This makes sure that the container activity has implemented
        // the callback interface. If not, it throws an exception
        try {
            mCallback = (Test) activity;
        } catch (ClassCastException e) {
            throw new ClassCastException(activity.toString()
                    + " must implement Test");
        }
    }


}



 public class MainActivity extends Activity
                implements FragmentA.Test{

               Fragment fragmentc=getFragmentManager().findFragmentByTag(FragmentC.class);



            public setTextChange(String ch) {
                     if(fragmentc!=null){

                      fragmentc.onChangeText(ch);
        }
            }
        }


        public class FragmenC extends Fragment{
            Test mCallback;


            public void onChangeText(String text){
        }


        }
```